# Pass excel Column/cell range to a MySQL/ MS query as parameter

Tags: mysql, excel, excel-2010, ms-query, vba

I have a MySQL query which in which I have to pass excel cells/columns as parameter.
i.e Select * from employee where name=? and joining_date=?

The above query has to pick the two parameters from cells in two columns name & joining_date from sheet 1 and populate in sheet 2.

Is there any way we could give more that one cell or whole column as parameter in MS query.

Comment: Done! through ADODB. Any other suggestions are welcome.